# Find total no of Close polygons iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, graph-algorithm, shapes

I want to find total number of close shape.

[image]

In image, there are 6 no of close polygons .
I have tried following method

```
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [arrLinesInfo count]; i++) {

              NSDictionary *dictLineInfo = [arrLinesInfo objectAtIndex:i];

              startPoint = CGPointMake([[dictLineInfo valueForKey:@"line_start_point_x"] doubleValue], [[dictLineInfo valueForKey:@"line_start_point_y"] doubleValue]);
              endPoint = CGPointMake([[dictLineInfo valueForKey:@"line_end_point_x"] doubleValue], [[dictLineInfo valueForKey:@"line_end_point_y"] doubleValue]);

              [self isCircularRoute:startPoint withEndPoint:endPoint];
            }


            -(void) isCircularRoute:(CGPoint) lineStartPoint withEndPoint:(CGPoint) lineEndPoint 
            {
                NSPredicate *pre= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"
    (self.line_end_point_x == '%f' && self.line_end_point_y == '%f') OR 
        (self.line_start_point_x == '%f' && self.line_start_point_y == '%f') OR 
        (self.line_end_point_x == '%f' && self.line_end_point_y == '%f') OR
         (self.line_start_point_x == '%f' && self.line_start_point_y == '%f')", lineStartPoint.x, 
        lineStartPoint.y,
         lineStartPoint.x,
        lineStartPoint.y,
         lineEndPoint.x,
         lineEndPoint.y,
         lineEndPoint.x,
         lineEndPoint.y]];

 NSMutableArray *arrSamePointRef = [[arrLinesInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre] mutableCopy];

 arrSamePointRef = [[arrSamePointRef filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"
(self.line_start_point_x != '%f' && self.line_start_point_y != '%f') &&
         (self.line_end_point_x != '%f' && self.line_end_point_y != '%f')", lineStartPoint.x
        , lineStartPoint.y
        , lineEndPoint.x
        , lineEndPoint.y]]] mutableCopy];//[arrSamePointRef removeObject:dictLineInfo];

                if(arrSamePointRef.count > 2){
                   totalPolygon = totalPolygon + 1;
                }
                NSLog(@"totalPolygon : ===== %tu", totalPolygon);

                for (NSDictionary *dictSingleLine in arrSamePointRef) {

                    CGPoint newStartPoint = CGPointMake([[dictSingleLine valueForKey:@"line_start_point_x"] doubleValue], [[dictSingleLine valueForKey:@"line_start_point_y"] doubleValue]);
                    CGPoint newEndPoint = CGPointMake([[dictSingleLine valueForKey:@"line_end_point_x"] doubleValue], [[dictSingleLine valueForKey:@"line_end_point_y"] doubleValue]);

                    [self isCircularRoute:newStartPoint withEndPoint:newEndPoint];

               }

            }
```

This is go in infinite loop.

I have all start point and end point object in array.
array object like below

> [
>     {
>       "point_start_lbl" : "a",
>       "point_end_lbl" : "b",
>       "line_start_point_x" : 200,
>       "line_start_point_y" : 10,
>       "line_end_point_x" : 100,
>       "line_end_point_y" : 10,
>     }, ...
>   ]

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your data dtructure. Do you only have a single array with a bunch of cgpoints? How do you know which points are connected?

Comment: 6 close path means what?

Comment: @rohit Sidpara : I think 6 close path means 6 polygons.

Comment: but this image have only three polygon

Comment: @rohitSidpara there is one outter shape with 5 nested shapes

Comment: @rohitSidpara: 3 "obvious" triangles, then 2 combinations of 2 triangles to get a square and a other quadrialtere, and the the combination of the 3 triangles give 6 figures ;)

Comment: @Larme : yes, you are right

Comment: Please state what you already did to solve the problem and where exactly you're having problems. SO is not for having others solve your programming tasks.

Comment: @Monish Use line to polygon algorithms for it, it will return shapes  and count of it.

Comment: There are graphs/nodes algorithms that could help you.

Comment: @rohitSidpara I took it to mean "close*d*".

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have a closed polygon if you have an ordered list of edges such that each edge ends on the vertex that the next starts on and no edge is repeated within the list.

I'm unclear about your data structure but I might therefore:

Define an object, `Edge` that identifies two vertices.

For each vertex, create an array containing every single edge that touches that vertex.

Then, something like, in Swift-ish pseudocode:

```
var successfulPaths: [Edge] = []
for edge in edges
{
    let usedEdges = [edge]
    attemptTraversalFrom(edge.vertex1, edge.vertex2, usedEdges, successfulPaths)
    attemptTraversalFrom(edge.vertex2, edge.vertex1, usedEdges, successfulPaths)
}

print("There were \(successfulPaths.count) successful paths")

[...]

func attemptTraversalFrom(startingVertex, endingVertex, usedEdges, successfulPaths) {
    let vertexEdges = endingVertex.edges
    for edge in (edges not in usedEdges) {
        let newEndingVertex = 
            (edge.vertex1 == endingVertex) ? edge.vertex2 : edge.vertex1

        if newEndingVertex == startingVertex {
            successfulPaths.add(usedEdges)
            return
        } else {
            let newUsedEdges = userEdges.addItem(edge)
            attemptTraversalFrom(startingVertex, newEndingVertex, newUsedEdges, successfulPaths)
        }
    }

    // Note: will automatically fall through to here and return
    // without adding anything to `successfulPaths` if there are
    // no further traversable edges
}
```

Extemporaneous, etc. A bit like the recursive part of Dijkstra's pathfinding algorithm, except that potential paths are accumulated rather than shorter paths eliminating longer ones prior to complete evaluation.

Comment: would you please help me to understand below line ?
'    for edge in (edges not in usedEdges) {'

Comment: It just means to pick as the next end vertex whichever you're not already at. I.e. on the edge you're on, walk along it from where you currently are to the other end.